Wordpress Custom Post Type using Snippet Code for Query ID fields on Posts
Here is my code to display only posts with the type "success-case," and I want to specify that only posts with the value "My Computer" in the column product_1_title should be shown. However, after I input this my_query into the query ID field, nothing happens in the posts widget.
function myQueryFilter($args, $widgetControlsValues) {
    
    $args['post_type'] = 'success-case';
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'product_1_title',
            'value'   => 'My Computer',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    );

    return $args;
}

add_filter('my_query', 'myQueryFilter', 10, 2);


I added a filter to modify the query for the posts widget. I set the post_type to 'success-case' and added a meta query to filter by the product_1_title field with the value 'My Computer'.

It's 'compare' => '%LIKE%' I think? Or 'value'   => '%"%My Computer%"%' maybe? 'value'   => '"My Computer"',?

Just to ask, is my_query a placeholder or your literal code?

As to the comment about %, WordPress automatically inserts those for LIKE queries, they shouldn't be manually added
